# Apex managed sharing limits?

Tags: apex, limits, sharing-rule, apex-managed-sharing, apex-sharing

I've implemented a User Managed Sharing Using Apex and need to know are there any limits for Apex User Managed Sharing for standard or for custom objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the notes in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_recalc.htm) apply:

> Apex sharing reasons and Apex managed sharing recalculation are only available for custom objects.
>
> Every time a custom object's organization-wide sharing default access level is updated, any Apex recalculation classes defined for associated custom object are also executed.
>
> The object’s organization-wide default access level must not be set to the most permissive access level. For custom objects, this level is Public Read/Write. For more information, see Understanding Sharing.

Aside from that, all standard [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) apply, so presumably you can't recalculate sharing on an object with more than 50,000,000 rows, nor can you create more than 10,000 sharing entries in a single pass. You'll also be subject to the 250,000 asynchronous calls per day limit (shared across all asynchronous jobs).

I don't see anything in the docs about any extra limitations.